# How to capture paste event on numberfield of extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 6.5.3. I want to show error message on paste of numbers in numberfield. It may be like ctrl+v or right click and then paste. So how can I achieve this. paste event of numberfield or textfield is not getting fired. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using modern or classic toolkit?

Comment: I think you want to validate the numberfield so that user should not paste special char/alphabets. So best way let him do it and `onChange` event check if input is number else throw error. Also its not necessary user is always pasting characters, user can also paste numbers. 
And if you know in Linux browser mouse central click paste the selection. So like there are different ways for pasting which I think handling all of them is not good approach to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'paste' event listener to achieve it. Something like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'On The Wall',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        name: 'bottles',
        fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
        value: 99,
        maxValue: 99,
        minValue: 0,
        

        enableKeyEvents: true, // In modern toolkit you do not need it..
        listeners: {
            paste: function() {
                console.log("ERROR COPY-PASTE!!!");
            }
        }
    }]
});
```